# Set mouse acceleration on linux

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, mouse

I am trying to set my mouse acceleration on linux mint 19.1.

I used to be able to use...

```
xset m 14/5 10
```

Where 14/15 is the accel ratio and 10 is the threshold in pixels per 10 ms.

Now in Linux Mint 19.1 this command has no effect.

Is there a new command I could use in 19.1 that would achieve the same goal?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that only works with the evdev driver, not libinput.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if my configs might work with a mouse because I have only used this for my touchpad. The pointer acceleration here is a part of the Xserver so should work for a mouse in addition to a touchpad.

Here is my /etc/X11/xorg.d.conf/60-pointer.conf file. Change the MatchProduct part to your mouse name and change to MatchIsPointer in here and see what happens:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "ELAN1300"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchProduct "ELAN1300:00"
  Option "AccelerationProfile" "1"
  Option "AccelerationScheme" "predictable"
  Option "AccelerationThreshold" "5"
  Option "AccelerationNumerator" "2"
  Option "AccelerationDenominator" "1"
  Option "ConstantDeceleration" "2.4"
  Option "AdaptiveDeceleration" "2.1"
EndSection
```